# How to create multiline ListBox in GWT?

Tags: html, css, gwt

In my project the value to show in GWT list-box is big(from database). So user is not able to see the full value at once.
For this I have decided to add display value in multiline.
I have used tags like \n and HTML tags like breakline but not getting the result. GWT compiler considering these tags as a string and showing in the list.
How can I do this. Can I apply customized css?

My code is as below:

```
ListBox getListBox(boolean dropdown) {

  String longText = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC";

  ListBox widget = new ListBox();
  widget.addStyleName("demo-ListBox");
  widget.addItem(longText);
  widget.addItem("Two");
  widget.addItem("Three");
  widget.addItem("Four");
  if(!dropdown)widget.setVisibleItemCount(3);
    return widget;
}
```

Comment: What about a Cell List instead: http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT `ListBox` simply wraps an HTML `select` element. Such element does not allow line breaks in its `option` values.

You can:

- change approach: use a short description with a longer `title` attribute;
- roll out your own widget, or use one already available (like the new [`GwtChosen`](https://github.com/jDramaix/gwtchosen)).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

It would be possible by using some JavaScript with CSS styling on HTML elements, easily or you'll have to build custom drop down list for such a thing..